# Difference Between File System Task & FTP Task in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ftp, filesystems, etl

I want to know the exact difference between FTP Task and File System Task i gone through some tutorials but i didn't get any major differences 
Can anyone help me out with this

Answer (score 2):

They give the same functionality but use complete different mechanics:

- **File System Task** is used to handle local or network (accessible, mapped drives) files. You can also change files properties to hide a file or make it read-only.
- **FTP Task** uses the *[File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)* to interact with an FTP server to move, create or delete files. This protocol involves a lot of communication procedures and handling to do these operations.

For an FTP communication you need a client and a server (that is a software running all the time listening to communications on one end), while in the File System Task the SSIS just interacts to the OS file system directly.